# How to combine a subset of the list of pairs and return the index of the last element

Tags: scala, dictionary, fold

Lets say I have a list of pairs sorted by the first element, that looks something like this:

```
List((0.0,0.001), (0.001,1.0), (1.0,2.0), (2.0,3.0), (3.0,4.0), (4.0,5.0), (5.0,15.0), (15.0,30.0), (30.0,45.0), (45.0,60.0), (60.0,71.0))
```

This is essentially a list of intervals.

Given a starting element, for example element 3 which corresponds to `(2.0,3.0)`, and an interval length, for example `40`, I want to find the interval index in which `40` ends up, if I start from index 3.

So essentially, for each element starting from (in this case) element 3, I need to perform `_._2 - _._1` and add them together, until the length exceeds 40. As soon as I reach it I need to stop. I don't wish to `map` the whole list to durations (the list can be quite long), and anyway I don't want to `foldLeft` all of them, I want to stop as soon as I reach the required duration. Its like the `break` of traditional imperative `for` loops.

This is quite simple if you were to do it imperatively using plain old Java. Is there any smart trick to do this in Scala the functional way?

Comment: I encourage you to create a real abstraction for you interval type. Tuples are weak abstractions, like maps and arrays and sets and whatnot.

Comment: Well, I can create an `Interval` case class that provides a `val` which computes the duration. I can also work with a simpler list of just the first numbers of each pair, because the second number is the same as the first number of the next pair (I have no gaps in my case) but essentially the information I have doesn't change that much, my issue is how to `foldLeft` (or accumulate in some way) a segment of a list, until I reach a certain criteria, and know how many elements were traversed to reach it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `scanLeft` is exactly what you're looking for—it lets you compute a running total:

```
def findIt(intervals: Seq[(Double, Double)], value: Double, start: Int): Int =
  start + intervals.drop(start).scanLeft(0.0) {
    case (acc, (b, e)) => acc + e - b
  }.tail.indexWhere(_ > value)
```

Or, possibly more clearly:

```
def intervalLength(interval: (Double, Double)) = interval._2 - interval._1

def findIt(intervals: Seq[(Double, Double)], value: Double, start: Int): Int =
  start + intervals
            .drop(start)
            .map(intervalLength)
            .scanLeft(0.0)(_ + _).tail.indexWhere(_ > value)
```

In your case this approach will compute the total for the entire list, but you can easily make it lazy by converting the input into a `Stream`. To show that this works, we can write the following, where `xs` is your example list:

```
scala> findIt(Stream.continually(xs).flatten, 40.0, 3)
res0: Int = 8
```

We've just run `findIt` on the infinite stream resulting from repeating your data forever, and we get a result immediately, so we're definitely not computing all the totals.

Comment: SO should have a mode, as in academia, where a contribution is made by a so-called lead author tutoring a hapless post-doc; and each gets credit.  Everyone benefits. I don't know where you spend SO credits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def indexOf(intervals: List[(Double, Double)], start: Int, interval: Double): Option[Int] = {
  def recur(el: List[(Double, Double)], pos: Int, remaining: Double): Option[Int] = {
    def duration(p: (Double, Double)): Double = p._2 - p._1
    el match {
      case head :: _ if remaining - duration(head) < 0 => Some(pos)
      case head :: _ => recur(el.tail, pos+1, remaining - duration(head))
      case Nil => None
    }
  }
  recur(intervals.drop(start), start, interval)
}
```

Example usage:

```
val intervals = List((0.0,0.001), (0.001,1.0), (1.0,2.0), (2.0,3.0), (3.0,4.0), (4.0,5.0), (5.0,15.0), (15.0,30.0), (30.0,45.0), (45.0,60.0), (60.0,71.0))
println(indexOf(intervals, 0, 0.0005))
println(indexOf(intervals, 0, 0.001))
println(indexOf(intervals, 3, 40d))
println(indexOf(intervals, 3, 200d))
```

Outputs:

```
Some(0)
Some(1)
Some(8)
None
```

Comment: Why would you use explicit recursion when there's a nice combinator that'll do the job so much more clearly?

Comment: I think it is useful to show the asker another approach considering they are less familiar with Scala. I will say this, as much as I like your answer, I disagree with the implication that recursion is only allowed when there is no way to chain collection calls together to get the same answer.

Comment: Fair enough—and I definitely wouldn't want to suggest that explicit recursion "shouldn't be allowed" in any sense, but I do think that fitting a problem into the constraints of a few recursive combinators (fold, scan, map) is one of the best ways to write better Scala code.

Comment: Not going to argue with that. Cheers.